# wxStaticBitmap with wxPtyhon at GTK+ not working

Tags: python, linux, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have such piece of code in wxPython:

```
        logo = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('picture.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
```

On Windows it works like a charm. But when I run my application on linux (SUSE) I get nothing but blank area of proper size (exactly the size of my png). The image **is** loaded, no errors thrown.

Notice that I use wxBitmapButtons as well:

```
self.butOK_ = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, label = u'&OK')
self.butOK_ .SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('ok.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wx.RIGHT)
```

And this works on both platforms.

What can be the problem, that under MSW everything looks fine, but on linux (wxGTK) my picture is not visible?
Maybe it is relevant that not loading picture ix 400x250 and those that work are only about 16x16 or up to 32x32?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, I discovered it by chance myself. But this behaviour varies between platforms so I will leave the question and post a correct answer:

I turns out, that for unknown reason, if `wxStaticBitmap` is owned by wxFrame it does work under Windows but fails with GTK+.

```
logo = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, wx.Bitmap('picture.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
```

The only necessary change was that it is now owned by a wxPanel, main panel on this frame and everything works same on both platforms.

Comment: You'll find that the panel also adds correct tab navigation and that the background color is correct cross-platform. I think the color is a little off if you just use a frame.